# Removing a css blur affect after user authentication - django

Tags: html, css, django, authentication

I am currently working on a project with Django. The home / main page of the project is locked behind a login form. I have the background blurred with the login form on top of the blur and I am looking to remove that form and blur when the user logs in with a valid account.

Is this possible and where should I look, googling has turned up nothing.

the blur is applied via css.

Also is it possible to stop the user from interacting with the elements behind the blur until they log in?

thank you

home.html

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class='login-form'>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class='larger-form'>
            <h3>Login Form</h3>
            <div class='smaller-form'>
                <p>
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password">
                </p>
                <button type="submit" class='login'>Login</button>
                Need an account? <a class='' href="{% url 'register-page' %}">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="search-content">
    <div class='bar-container'>
        <h1> Search Here </h1>
    </div>
    <div class='searchbar-container'>
        <p>
            <input type="text" class="search-bar">
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class='content-section'>

    </div>
</div>


    <style>

        .search-content {
            filter: blur(4px);
        }

        .login-form {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin: auto;
            width: 20%;
            height: 30%;
            display: grid;
            z-index: 3;

        }

        .search-bar {
            border-radius: 2px;
            width: 40%;
            margin-left: 30%;

        }

        .bar-container {
            filter: blur(4px);
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            background-color: #545452;
            border-radius: 3px;
            width: 75%;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px grey;
        }

        .searchbar-container {
            margin: auto;
            right: 50%;
        }

        h3 {
            color: white;
        }

        .loginform {
            margin-top: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 300px;

        }

        .larger-form {
            margin-top: 25px;
            background-color: #545452;
            border: 3px solid #545452;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px grey;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .smaller-form {
            background-color: white;
            text-align: left;
        }

        .login {
            border: none;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .login:hover {
            color: #42A5F5;

    </style>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='bar'>
                <a href="{% url 'main-home' %}" class='button'>Home</a>
                <a href="{% url 'register-page' %}" class='button'>Sign up</a>
            </div>
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class='menu-bottom'>
            <div id='colorstrip'>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
    <style>
        .container {
            position:fixed;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;

            top:0;
            left:0;

            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: white;
        }

        .bar {
            background-color: #545452;
            padding-top: 10px;
            height: 50px;
            align-items: end;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
            border-radius: 1.5px;
        }

        .button {
            float: right;
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-right: 20px;
            border: none;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 18px;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: #545452;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .button:hover {
            color: #42A5F5;
        }

        .menu-bottom {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #colorstrip{
            width: 100%;
            height: 0px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #545452;
            border-radius: 1px;
            background-color: white;
        }

    </style>
</html>
```

Let me know if any other code is needed or if this is formatted incorrectly.

Comment: If possible, post some code. It would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can wrap the inline CSS code like so:

`{% if not user.is_authenticated %}filter: blur(4px);{% endif %}`

Also, you can disable interaction with the BG content by adding `pointer-events: none;` to the class of the element above the content you don't want interacted with.

Comment: Also, try to read more about documentation of twig
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/

Comment: @myonline Thank you for the comment, but it seems twig is for PHP, whereas OP is using Django/Python

Comment: hello @Hybrid, I thought he was using Symfony framework, twig can be also used for HTML as myself currently using for development for Frontend, btw, thanks for the response :)